# How to expose a image without saving to the public folder of Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm making an application in Laravel where I need to save images that can not be accessible in the public folder along with my `js` and `css`.

I'm saving the images in the default Laravel folder, the `storage/app` folder. I wanted to know a way to expose these images without putting them in the `public` folder. I figured I could search the image first and send it to the view along with other data such as the user name and something else, but I'm not sure how to do it.

My configuration in the `filesystems.php` looks like this:

**filesystems.php**

```
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],
```

In my view, I'm trying like this:

```html
<img src="{{ url("files/{$file->getContent()}") }}" class="rounded-circle">
```

In this case, I'm trying to put an image that the user uploaded.

Comment: you need to download the file as a binary `return Response::download('path/to/file')`. The storage folder isn't in the public folder.

Comment: @adam What? I did not understand that

Comment: @adam At the moment, I want to show an image. I even managed to show but I had to create the symbolic link for this

Comment: you need to create symbolic link, via php aritsan storage:link, check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: @ankitpatel I've done this before, but I'm afraid other people might have access to other images from other users. I'm afraid a whole folder is publicly accessible and I do not want to. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Comment: What do you mean by "expose"? If you have the URL in the HTML source, wouldn't it be considered as exposed? In this sense, wouldn't @adam's first comment be the right answer (instead of the answer below)?

Comment: @JohnDoe It's not like that. I want to know if there is any security problem in leaving sensitive files in the public folder together with css and js. I'm afraid someone can have access to images that should not, should I create the symbolic link.

Is there a way to create a link to display an image (for example, a profile image) from the storage / app directory?

Answer (score 2):

Create and endpoint to download your file:

```
Route::get('/file/download', function() {
    // get your filepath
    $filepath = 'path/to/image/image.png';
    return Response::download($filepath);
});
```

Then in your view:

```
<img src="{{url('/file/download')}}" class="rounded-circle" />
```

Comment: i think you rather should use action here instead of url :)

Comment: @addi2113 Yes that would be the desired implementation. This just illustrates the concept of protecting assets.